# Why does `runScript =` in `buildFHSUserEnv` stop after first line when using two single quotes?

Tags: nix, nixos

Running the below `shell.nix` using `nix-shell ./shell.nix` gives the expected output:

```hs
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

(pkgs.buildFHSUserEnv {
  name = "test";
  runScript = "
    echo one
    echo two
  ";
}).env
```

```
one
two
```

as expected.

But changing the double quotes to two single quotes only seems to execute the first line of `runScript`:

```hs
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

(pkgs.buildFHSUserEnv {
  name = "test";
  runScript = ''
    echo one
    echo two
  '';
}).env
```

```
one
```

This is strange, since both quoting styles do evaluate to multi-line strings with all the lines I entered:

```sh
$ nix-instantiate --eval -                                                                                                                                                                                          
"
  first line
  second line
"
"\n  first line\n  second line\n"
```

```sh
$ nix-instantiate --eval -                                                                                                                                                                                               
''
  first line
  second line
''
"first line\nsecond line\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`runScript` isn't treated as a proper bash script, but is rather pasted directly after the beginning of an `exec` statement.

The generated code becomes either

```sh
exec
echo one
echo two
```

or

```sh
exec echo one
echo two
```

because `''` removes the starting newline.

`exec` by itself is a no-op in bash, so that happens to behave as expected, but `exec echo one` replaces the shell interpreter by an `echo one` process, which is not what you intended.

Seems like the `runScript` parameter should be deprecated and replaced by two optional ones which are self-explanatory, unless this behavior is caused by a recent change, which would make it a regression (bug).